# ML Algorithm to determine probability that voter will vote in future election

Tags: python, machine-learning

I have a dataset that includes voter ids along with their demographics, education, marital status, etc as well as a few binary variables indicating if they have participated in previous primary/general elections. Is there an algorithm that will 1. Classify whether someone will vote in a *future election* and 2. return the probability of that event?

Comment: Well, that's really what you have to decide, right?  You have to figure out what kind of machine learning algorithm is going to produce the results you want.  There's no single algorithm that works for every situation.  You have to know the problem domain.

Comment: I guess that's what I'm trying to get at. i was thinking a Multivariable Logistic Regression since I want to have a binary output (1 they vote in the future election, 0 they don't) and then also want to incorporate their data on whether or not they voted in previous elections.

Comment: You can look for a broader field as a "churn prediction" (this is very similar and well known application type) where the model in theory returns P(customer churn | input), very similar problem but instead of predicting probabilty of preservation (your case), the probabilty of customer churn is predicted. You can adapt the procedures to your case.

Answer (score 0):

In this case [Logistic regression](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.LogisticRegression.html) will work fine, but I suggest to try out KNN and Decision Trees/[Random Forest](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.ensemble.RandomForestClassifier.html?highlight=random%20forest#sklearn.ensemble.RandomForestClassifier) since you said to have many binary labels. And I suggest some exploratory data analysis (anything goes) before trying to come up with model selection.

Comment: Thanks! I considered Logistic Regression, but in terms of carrying out the algorithm, since the future election didn't happen yet, would I just create a blank column, say "future_election_probability" and then train on ~20% of the data and then use that to test on the other ~80%? I'm not sure how to incorporate the fact that previous election data has been included.